# Asp.Net Core - EF Core - AspNetCoreIdentity - 1 context with 2 databases

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

In my ASP.net Core 5 project with EF Core 5, I have two separated contexts:

1. MSAContext which connects to the "MSA" database and consists of several tables showing me material;
2. AppIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext which connects to the "REGIDD" database and contains the tables created by AspNetCore.Identity for user management.

I need to create a tabular page that shows me the contents of the table "Material" (ID, name, location, serial...) of the database "MSA" and one of the columns I need to show is "Worked by" (which currently contains the ID that corresponds to the primary key of the dbo.AspNetUsers table of the database "REGIDD").

How do I create a single DBContext that connects to both databases?

PS: Sorry about my bad English. I hope I have made myself clear.

Comment: You can't. You need 2 DbContexts.

Comment: 2 distinct databases needs two different contexts (without having to do some awful hacking). Why would you even want to put them inside one?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.